# When returning a 2D array from a custom Google Sheets function, the values that are retrieved from a class are left blank

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, scripting

I'm sorry if the title is a bit confusing. Basically I have a custom Google Sheets function that receives a cell range as the argument. I have a class names Employee with a constructor that takes an ID as an argument and saves the value in a variable. In the custom function I create an array called Employees and for each value in the range I add a new instance of the Employee class with that value as the constructor argument. I then create an empty array called IDs and loop through each element in the Employees array and add the ID value saved in the class to the new array. If I return the IDs array, then when I call the function on google sheets, the list of items will appear vertically. However, if I instead create a 2D array and add the IDs variable as one of the elements while creating a new array with fixed elements as the second value. If I return that new 2D array, when I call the function the Ids array should be printed horizontally on the adjacent cells and the values of the second array should be printed underneath. However, the IDs are not printed, only the values of the second array are printed. If after looping through the Employees array and adding their Ids to the IDs array I add a a constant value, then only that value is printed when calling the function. This only happens when I return a 2D array, If I just return the IDs, they are all printed.

In the function bellow, when calling the chart function on Google Sheets, the ids array will be left blank on the sheet.

```
class Employee{
  constructor(employee){
    this.employeeID = employee;
  }
}
function chart(employeeIDs){
  employees = [];
  for(x = 0; x < employeeIDs.length; x++)
    employees.push(new Employee(employeeIDs[x]));
  ids = [];  
  for(x = 0; x < employees.length; x++)
    ids.push(employees[x].employeeID);
  vehicles = ["Car", "road", "bus", "Plane", "Submarine"];
  return [ids, vehicles];
}
```

If I change the return to...

```
return ids
```

Then when the function is called the list of items in ids are printed.
If I add additional values to the ids array after adding the values from the Employee class, such as...

```
ids = [];  
for(x = 0; x < employees.length; x++)
  ids.push(employees[x].employeeID);
ids.push(12)
vehicles = ["Car", "road", "bus", "Plane", "Submarine"];
return [ids, vehicles];
'''
Then only the number 12 is printed at the end, plus the entire contents of the vehicles array.
```

Comment: I guess that the reason of your issue might be due to that each column length of each row is different. But in order to correctly replicate your situation, can you provide the sample formula you are using? And by the way, can I ask you about the relationship between `If I change the return to...` and your top and bottom scripts?

Comment: I appreciate your help, I actually managed to narrow down the problem and re submitted the problem in a much more easy to understand way. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64725858/on-google-sheets-custom-functions-with-a-range-as-an-argument-when-trying-to-ret

Comment: Thank you for replying. I checked it and post an answer. Could you please confirm it. If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize. By the way, At the custom function, it seems that when the array is 2 dimensional array, each column length is not required to be the same like `const sample = () => [[1, 2, 3], [1], [, 2, 3], [1, 2]];`. So my 1st comment is my mistake. I deeply apologize for this. And how will you do your this question?

Comment: How does the cell range look like? @RubenWoodard