# On Google Sheets custom functions with a range as an argument when trying to return a value in that argument as a 2D array, that value isn't printed

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, scripting

If I call the following function from a Google Sheets cell by typing "=chart(A2:A5, B2:B5" nothing is printed, not even an error message. What I expect to be printed are two rows, one containing the contents of A2:A5 and the other containing the contents of B2:B5.

```
function chart(range, range2){
  return [range, range2];
}
```

However, if I return a 2D array that does not contain the values of the argument, then it does display the information properly. If I call "=chart(A2:A5, B2:B5" two rows will be created, the first containing the list of vehicles, and bellow that one the list of numbers.

```
function chart(range, range2){
  vehicles = ["airplane", "motorcycle", spaceship]
  numbers = [43, 29, 11]
  return [vehicles, numbers];
}
```

If I do a combination, as shown bellow, the first row will be left blank, and the second row will contain the list of vehicles.

```
function chart(range, range2){
  vehicles = ["airplane", "motorcycle", "spaceship"]
  return [range, vehicles];
}
```

For the last example, I took a single value from the "range" argument and added it to an array within an array. This time, the first row will have a list of vehicles and the second row will contain the values "1, 2,  , 3" with a blank between the 2 and the 3.

```
function chart(range, range2){
  vehicles = ["airplane", "motorcycle", spaceship, "submarine"]
  numbers = [1, 2, range[0], 3]
  return [vehicles, numbers];
}
```

In sum, every time I try to return a 2D array containing the value of an argument (or the entire argument), that / those value(s) are left blank on Google Sheets. And it only happens with 2D arrays. Returning 2D arrays works just find in all other cases where I don't include the values of an argument within the array.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For your question, please be careful the following rule for the custom function.

- As the returned values of the custom function, those are number, string, boolean, 1 dimensional array, 2 dimensional array.
- When `=chart(A2:A5, B2:B5)` is put to a cell, at Google Apps Script side, `A2:A5` and `B2:B5` are 2 dimensional arrays including the cell values, respectively.

From above rule, I think that the reason of your issue is that 2 dimensional array is put to `[]`. In this case, it's 3 dimensional array. I would like to answer for each script as follows.

In your situation, it supposes that `=chart(A2:A5, B2:B5)` is put to a cell for each script.

#### Answer 1:

About the following script,

```
function chart(range, range2){
  return [range, range2];
}
```

I think that the reason of your issue is that when `=chart(A2:A5, B2:B5)` is put to a cell, `A2:A5` and `B2:B5` are 2 dimensional array. For example, `A2:A5` is like `[['a2'],['a3'],['a4'],['a5']]`. By this, `[range, range2]` is 3 dimensional array. When the array is used as the returned value for the custom function, 1 and 2 dimensional arrays can be used.

When you want to put the values like `[range, range2]`, it is required to merge `range` and `range2` as follows.

```
function chart(range, range2){
  return range.concat(range2);
}
```

If you want to put `range, range2` to 2 rows, the script is as follows.

```
function chart(range, range2){
  return [range.flat(), range2.flat()];
}
```

#### Answer 2:

About the following script,

```
function chart(range, range2){
  vehicles = ["airplane", "motorcycle", "spaceship"]
  numbers = [43, 29, 11]
  return [vehicles, numbers];
}
```

In this case, `vehicles` and `numbers` are 1 dimensional array. By this, `[vehicles, numbers]` is 2 dimensional array, and each values are put to the cells for each row. It seems that even when 3 dimensional array is returned, no error occurs.

#### Answer 3:

About the following script,

```
function chart(range, range2){
  vehicles = ["airplane", "motorcycle", "spaceship"]
  return [range, vehicles];
}
```

In this case, `range` and `vehicles` are 2 dimensional array and 1 dimensional array. By this, `range` of `[range, vehicles]` cannot be put to the cells, while `vehicles` is put.

#### Answer 4:

About the following script,

```
function chart(range, range2){
  vehicles = ["airplane", "motorcycle", spaceship, "submarine"]
  numbers = [1, 2, range[0], 3]
  return [vehicles, numbers];
}
```

In this case, when `spaceship` is declared at elsewhere, `range[0]` is 1 dimensional array like `[1, 2, [#, #, #,,,], 3]`. Because `range` is 2 dimensional array. It seems that when the elements are the number and 1 dimensional array, the 1 dimensional array is not put. For example, when `[1, 2, range[0], 3]` is modified to `[1, 2, range[0][0], 3]`, `range[0][0]` can be put.

#### Note:

- At the custom function, it seems that when the array is 2 dimensional array, each column length is not required to be the same like `const sample = () => [[1, 2, 3], [1], [, 2, 3], [1, 2]];`.

#### Reference:

- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)